# How to append line at end of file using File.Append in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamwriter

I am creating a txt file using c# and writing multiple lines. The problem is that line is getting appended at top and not at end.

Any info on how to achieve this. 
This is below code

```
    private static void WriteReleaseSql( string sqlStatement)
    {
        string ReleaseoutputFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReleaseOutputFilePath"];

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(ReleaseoutputFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(sqlStatement);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To me this code works as expected. The line will be appended at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StreamWriter` without `FileStream` (user instance) and it works fine for me

```
private static void WriteReleaseSql( string sqlStatement)
{
    string ReleaseoutputFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReleaseOutputFilePath"];

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ReleaseoutputFilePath,True))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(sqlStatement);
    }
}
```

*Note: your code works fine*

Comment: Only without a "visible" stream. There still is one.

Comment: I agree with that

Answer (score 1):

When I checked MDSN Website for [`FileMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx),this is the definition I got.

> Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file. This requires `FileIOPermissionAccess`. Append
>   permission. `FileMode.Append` can be used only in conjunction with
>   `FileAccess.Write`. Trying to seek to a position before the end of the
>   file throws an `IOException` exception, and any attempt to read fails
>   and throws a `NotSupportedException` exception.

As far as the doc goes, it should append things at the end. Please check the output again.

I would really like to know how to add things at the top, though.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Environment.NewLine` to add a new line.